# How can I run Django application tests together with other tests?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I’m working on a project composed of two Python packages. `foo` contains some common business logic and `foo.webapp` contains a Django app providing an API over it. Module `foo.tests` contains `unittest` cases for the common logic, and `foo.webapp.tests` for the API. Plus there’s a Django project for running the API. So it looks like this:

```
foo-root/
    foo/
        __init__.py
        some_logic.py
        other_logic.py
        tests.py
        webapp/
            __init__.py
            urls.py
            views.py
            tests.py

    django_project/
        manage.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
```

I want to keep `foo.tests` separate from `foo.webapp.tests`, so when I do `django_project/manage.py test`, it should only run the latter. But I also want a way to run both test suites together, with one progress bar, one fail count etc. Can I accomplish this, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a custom Django test runner along the lines of [django-alltestsrunner](https://github.com/rangespan/django-alltestsrunner) (but instead of discovering the tests automatically, I specify a list of modules in `settings`).

Now, when I do `django_project/manage.py test`, it runs all the tests. When I do `django_project/manage.py test foo.webapp.tests`, it runs only the API tests.